# Gradle is using the STDOUT to log Jetty shutdown

Tags: java, jetty, gradle, slf4j, logback

I'm using Jetty as a web server and starting it programatically. The project is using Gradle. For logging I use sl4j with logback implementation.
In order to stop the server, I use a `org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.LifeCycle.` Everything works perfect in production.

However, my problem is that when I run unit tests from gradle, the Jetty shutdown service, from a different thread, is logging INFO level messages to STDOUT. This should not happen, because all other INFO messages which are printed from the [main] thread, are not shown.

Theoretically, this INFO logs should only be there when gradle is started with `"--info"`.

Does anyone know why is Gradle mapping Jetty INFO logs to STDOUT?

P.S. there is no configuration file for logback in unit tests.

Here is the first log message which shows up when running

```
gradle integrationTest
```

```
<code>11:30:25.553 [Thread-8] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - Graceful shutdown SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8984</code>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default everything that is printed to stdout in your tests is printed out in gradle. This makes me believe that for some reason your INFO log messages from the other thread are being printed to stdout. Can you verify if that is the case?

If you don't care if that's the case and you simply don't want to see anything from test stdout then there is a way to disable all output from tests in Gradle:

```
integrationTest {
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = false
}
```

Comment: I can hide these INFO messages from gradle also with 'logging.captureStandardOutput Level.INFO'. But I would like to know why is this hapennig. It could be some problems that I oversee and I don't want to just cover them. Seems pretty strange that the Jetty ShutdownThread is printing these logging after Gradle has finished running the tests.

Comment: Can you share the way you are starting and stopping jetty in your tests?